# Global dimension of power series ring $k[[x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}]]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be the power series ring $k[[x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}]]$ over a field $k$. Notice that $R$ is a noetherian local ring with residue field $k$. Show that $gl. \dim(R)=pd_{R}(k)=n$.

By First Change of Rings Theorem, we know that
$$pd_{R}(k)=1+pd_{R/(x_{1})}(k)$$

Hence by induction, it is easy to see that $pd_{R}(k)=n$.

So we need to show that for any ideal $I$ of $R$, we have $pd_{R}(R/I)\leqslant n$. However, I have no idea about how to show it. Can anyone give some hints? Thank you very much.

Also notice that since $R$ is noetherian, we have $\mathrm{Tor-}\dim(R)=gl. \dim(R)$. So maybe it would be easier to show that $\mathrm{Tor-}\dim(R)\leqslant n$.

Comment: From what you have shown, it follows that for any finitely generated module $M$, $\mathrm{Tor}^i(M,k)=0$ for $i>n$. Can you now use an induction to finish the proof?

Comment: Since $fd(k)\leqslant pd(k)=n$, for any module $M$, we always have $\mathrm{Tor}^{i}(M, k)=0$ for $i>n$. But how to relate it to $\mathrm{Tor-}\dim (R)$?

Comment: Show that (using induction), projective dimension of any finitely generated module is at most $n$. Remember that for such a module, $\mathrm{Tor}^1(M,k)=0$ if and only if $M$ is free.

Comment: How to show that the projective (or torsion) dimension of $M$ is at most $n$ provided that $\mathrm{Tor}^{i}(M, k)=0$ for $i>n$? Using induction on the number of generators?

Comment: Show by induction $pd M\leq r$ if $Tor^r(M,k)=0$, No, do not use the number of generators, except for the $r=1$ case.